# Jersey returns an IPv6 address even when "java.net.preferIPv4Stack" is "true"

Tags: java, jersey, ip, ipv6, ipv4

[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) returns an IPv6 address even in the following code where I explicitly set the Java property `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` to `true`, while I would like to retrieve an IPv4 address:

```
@Path("/getip")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class PublicIp {

    @GET
    public Response getPublicIp(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
        String address = req.getRemoteAddr();
        return Response.ok(address).build();
    }
}
```

Which returns `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` if consumed locally. How can I force Jersey to return an IPv4 format?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing this to the JVM:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

On start instead of setting it as a system property inside the method to get an IP.